# Calculating a date of expiration with shell commands

Tags: bash, shell, date, grep

I am writing a code which would check my proxy expiration date. I manage to calculate the expiration date only by adding hours to present time, but would now also like to include minutes and seconds. I run `arcproxy --info` and the output that I am interested in (among other lines) says e.g. `Time left for proxy: 45 hours 55 minutes 10 seconds`. I am now wondering what would be the shortest way to extract all three (h, m, s) parameters and add them to `date`?

What I currently have is
`PROXY_VALIDITY=$(arcproxy --info | grep -oE "proxy: [0-9]+" | grep -oE "[0-9]+")`
which extracts the hours and then I simply add it to date by `date -d "+$PROXY_VALIDITY hours"`.

Of course I could use multiple `grep` commands to define also minutes and seconds similarly but I am interesting in the easiest and cleanest code..

EDIT: I found that `arcproxy` has a flag `-i validityEnd` which gives the validity end timestamp so this is now much easier to implement, but I am still looking for answers on my question above to learn something new.

EDIT: Output of `arcproxy --info` command:

```
Subject: /C=<C>/O=<O>/O=<O>/OU=<OU>/CN=<name>/CN=<CN>
Issuer: /C=<C>/O=<O>/O=<O>/OU=<OU>/CN=<name>
Identity: /C=<C>/O=<O>/O=<O>/OU=<OU>/CN=<name>
Time left for proxy: 44 hours 24 minutes 46 seconds
Proxy path: /tmp/x509up_u3431
Proxy type: X.509 Proxy Certificate Profile RFC compliant impersonation proxy - RFC inheritAll proxy
Proxy key length: 2048
Proxy signature: sha512
====== AC extension information for VO ======
VO        : vo
subject   : /C=<C>/O=<O>/O=<O>/OU=<OU>/CN=<name>
issuer    : /DC=<C>/DC=<DC>/OU=<OU>/CN=<name>
uri       : <url>:15001
attribute : <attribute>
attribute : <attribute>
tag       : <tag>:nickname=gasar8
Time left for AC: 44 hours 25 minutes 1 second
```

where things in `< >` are my personal data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
date -d "now +$(arcproxy --info|cut -f2 -d:)"
```

Also as per your question edit:

```
date -d@$(arcproxy -i validityEnd) # Change flag with appropriate argument
```

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately ```arcproxy --info``` produces multiple lines with ":" delimeter so this would work if the output would only be the line mentioned in question. I will edit the question to give full ouptut of the ```arcproxy --info``` command.

Comment: @gasar8 then insert the apropiate greping pipe before cut: `date -d "now +$(arcproxy --info|grep -F 'Time left for proxy'|cut -f2 -d:)"`

Comment: Thank you. Concerning the EDIT section, yes, I figured that out, just for completeness (because I was again not specific enough) can you change the flag, which is actually ```-i validityEnd``` so that I can accept the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Piping the output into awk is an option:

```
arcproxy --info | awk -F: '/Time left for proxy/ { system("date -d +\""$2"\"") }'
```

Find the right output line, set the field delimiter to : and then utilise the hours minutes and seconds output to build a date command to execute with awk's system function

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Similarly to the other answer, the ouput of ```arcproxy --info``` is a multiliner with many ":" delimeters, so I added the ```grep``` in between, to find the right line.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use grep with awk. You can search for the text required by adding it to the begging of the awk statement. I have amended the answer.. It should also be more efficient than multiple grep pipes.